How to get the transaction data or logs from a titanoboa `VyperContract` function call?
I have a contract called my_erc20 of the VyperDeployer that I can make VyperFunction calls on:
response = my_erc20.transfer(to, 123)

The response will be whatever the transfer function returned. How would I get the transaction dict/logs from this transaction/function call?

Use the get_logs function:
    my_erc20.transfer(to, 123)
    my_erc20.get_logs()[0].topics[0]

